# Auto-fill Drop Down Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have data that looks like this on a data sheet for a workbook:

| NAME 1 | NAME 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Jeff |

I would like to make drop-down cells on another sheet that would auto-fill the other column, depending on whichever was filled first.

For example, if I were to fill in Jeff for NAME 2, Bob would automatically appear for `NAME 1`, or if I were to fill in Bob for NAME 1, Jeff would appear for `NAME 2`. Is this possible?

I have been using the `VLOOKUP()` function in NAME 2, however, that restricts me to only using NAME 1 for searching via drop-down.

I'd appreciate any help or ideas!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). This needs `VBA` worksheet change event.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance VBA would be required because of circular referencing. However, formulas can be "safely" created where calculation is stopped before it gets to performing a circular reference. One way of stopping it is to use `IF()` statements. To solve your other ask, upgrading to `XLOOKUP()` allows returning array values from either direction AND has the added benefit of  error trapping (screenshot rows 4 & 5).

Armed with this knowledge a formula can be inserted into both `Name1` and `Name2`. If formulas for a particular row exists for both columns then return a blank. This stops the calucation so no circular reference is computed.

However, when a formula is overwritten in `Name1` by an actual value then the formula in `Name2` will evaluate to false and return the  `XLOOKUP()` and vice versa. For example:[image]

In the screenshot I have used conditional formatting to show where the formula still exist (green) vs where the formula was overwritten with a value.

Note this requires recopying the formula back if a row was to be reused.

column A code example: `=IF(ISFORMULA(B6),"",XLOOKUP(B6,$D$2:$D$6,$C$2:$C$6,"not in col2",0))`

Column B code example: `=IF(ISFORMULA(A6),"",XLOOKUP(A6,$C$2:$C$6,$D$2:$D$6,"not in col1",0))`

----edit----

I just tested and you can overlay drop down data validation to this solution:

[image]